# Composer install \ update authentication errors

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php, phpstorm

When I'm trying to install dependency from my private repository and I'm getting the following error:

```
> /opt/lampp/bin/php /home/arthur/Sites/audio-video-caption.com/composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Failed to clone the git@github.com:Djevil83/UserBundle.git repository, try running in interactive mode so that you can enter your GitHub credentials


  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                        
  Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@github.com:Djevil83/UserBundle.git' '/home/arthur/.cache/composer/vcs/git-github.com-Djevil83-UserBundle.git/'  


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...


Process finished with exit code 1 at 15:40:11.
Execution time: 1 874 ms.
```

`

Here is my `composer.json` :

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:Djevil83/UserBundle.git"
    },
]
```

I'm using Debian 8 and Xampp with php 7.

I don't know where is the error... thanks for your help !

Comment: Please confirm if you created github auth token and configured composer to used.

Comment: @AlexBlex Can you develop please. I'm a noob...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, confirm you setup access to the repo: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/ so you can clone it using your private key. The command:

```
git clone git@github.com:Djevil83/UserBundle.git
```

should create a new directory `UserBundle` without asking password.

Then read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#api-rate-limit-and-oauth-tokens how to setup OAuth token to increase rate limit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no repo `UserBundle` , see https://github.com/Djevil83?tab=repositories. Maybe the `UtilitiesBundle` is the proper one.
So try to change the line to

`"url": "git@github.com:Djevil83/UtilitiesBundle.git`

in your `composer.json` .

Comment: UserBundle is a private repo. I can see it in Github

Comment: Then alex-blex' comment seems to be reasonable - you need your git command  to authenticate istself.

Comment: @AlexBlex Yes I did it too.

Comment: Great, than you can proceed with OAuth token

Comment: @AlexBlex It works  ;) ! Now I have another problem, but It will be for a new Question in another Post...  Thanks for your help everybody !